# How to stop flex item overflowing outside parent when height is 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you look at the example snippet, I am trying to get `#feature_header_container` (in red) to expand to fill the remaining height left in `header` but because I have other content inside the `header` like the `<p>` shown, when I set `height: 100%` to `#feature_header_container` it overflows outside `header` but I want it to only expand the remaining height of `header`, how can I do this?

Right now, `#feature_header_container` (in red) is overflowing outside of `header` and gets pushed down by the first `<p>` element inside `header`.

```css
*
{
 font-family: Arial;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header
{
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: #21D4FD;
 background-image: linear-gradient(19deg, #21D4FD 0%, #B721FF 100%);

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.57); 
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);

 border-radius:  0 0 80px 80px;

 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
}

#p_test
{
  display: inline-block;
}

#feature_header_container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
}

#feature_container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.feature_box {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>

    <header>
    
    <p id="p_test">
    Test Test Test
    </p>

      <div id="feature_header_container">

        <div id="feature_container">

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </header>
    
    <main>
      <p>TesttestTesttestTesttestTesttestTesttest</p>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to coming across this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/LmYay/

I managed to solve my problem and have a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/p459qvfk/2/

The working example copied over:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* align items in Main Axis */
  align-items: stretch;
  /* align items in Cross Axis */
  align-content: stretch;
  /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #21D4FD;
  background-image: linear-gradient(19deg, #21D4FD 0%, #B721FF 100%);

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);

  border-radius: 0 0 80px 80px;

  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

#p_test {
  display: inline-block;
}

#feature_header_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
}

#feature_container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.feature_box {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>

    <header>

      <p id="p_test">
        Test Test Test
      </p>

      <p id="p_test">
        Test Test Test
      </p>

      <div id="feature_header_container">

        <div id="feature_container">

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

          <div class="feature_box">
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </header>

    <main>
      <p>TesttestTesttestTesttestTesttestTesttest</p>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```